# How to use credentials when using API to fetch custom field Id

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm a newbie and I am still in the learning phase.

Environment: JIRA Server.

I tried writing this simple program to fetch custom field ID using Python.

Code :

```
import requests


def custom_fields():
    response = requests.get("https://"JIRA URL"/rest/api/2/field")

#  # To test the response is working you need to get an output : 200
# print(response)
#
# # This will give you the output in String
# print(response.text)
# print(type(response.text))
#
# If you want to get the output in JSON format then try the
# following which will give you the output in list format.
#
# print (response.json())
# print(type(response.json()))

my_fields = response.json()

for field in my_fields:
    print(" Field Name :  {} Field Id : {}".format(field['name'], field['id']))


custom_fields()
```

and getting an sample output as:

```
Field Name : Key Field Id : issuekey
Field Name : Time Spent Field Id : timespent
Field Name : Original Estimate Field Id : timeoriginalestimate
Field Name : Project Field Id : project
Field Name : Σ Time Spent Field Id : aggregatetimespent
```

I believe this is because I am not using credentials to authenticate in the code. I tried following the link:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/
and tried updating the variable as:

```
response = requests.get ("curl -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://"JIRA URL"/rest/api/2/field")
```

and getting an error:

```
"No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "curl -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://"JIR URL"rest/api/2/field"
```

Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right. You've missed the authentication to send a request to the API endpoint.

It can be done in two ways:

- Using Basic Auth

```
headers = {
      'Authorization': '<Basic Auth Token>',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.request("GET", JIRA_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
```

- Using JIRA-Token-Based Authentication

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("demo_email@demo.com", "<JIRA_api_token>")

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)
```

For more details, you can always refer to their [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issue-fields/#api-rest-api-2-field-get)

Comment: I believe you can generate API token if you are using a cloud platform. Our JIRA is running in a server version.

Comment: Alright, then you can use the Basic Auth for the authentication to send the request to JIRA API.

Comment: Exactly, I updated the code as below and it all worked. Thanks a lot for the support

Comment: import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def custom_fields():
    response = requests.get(
        'https://'JIRA URL'/rest/api/2/field',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('UserName', 'Password'))

Answer (score 0):

```
header ={"Accept':'application/json",'authorization':f'Bearer {token}'}
response=request.get("{link}",headers=header)
print(response.json())
```

I think this might help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).